# How to randomly create groups with different numbers of rows in HP Vertica

Tags: sql, vertica

I'd like to randomly select 4 groups of data with different numbers of rows from a table, and generate a new column of group_name.

For example, if the original table (containing 10000 rows) was like this:

```
ID
---
ID1
ID2
...
```

The resulting table (containing 2750 rows) I want is like the following:

```
ID   GROUP
---  -----
ID1  1
ID2  3
...  ...
```

The number of rows for each group are like the following:

```
group1 1000 rows
group2 1000 rows
group3 500 rows
group4 250 rows
```

These randomly generated groups should not have any overlapping in rows.

Is there any way to do this in Vertica at one time rather than do the random select step by step?

Thanks!

Comment: So a parameter is the number of row for each group ? There is same number of rows as total of groups?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Yes, the only parameter is the number of rows for each group. I updated the question to make it easier to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [row_number](https://my.vertica.com/docs/5.0/HTML/Master/10967.htm)

and using a **[CTE](http://verticadatabaseblog.blogspot.com/)**

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT ID, row_number() over () as RN
    FROM YourTable
)
SELECT ID,
   CASE 
      WHEN rn <= 1000 then 1
      WHEN rn <= 2000 then 2
      WHEN rn <= 2500 then 3
      WHEN rn <= 2750 then 4
  END as GROUP
FROM cte
WHERE rn <= 2750
```

If you want more random you can create a `random` column and order by random on the `row_number() over (order by random)` function

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
SELECT ID, randomint(4)+1 as GROUP
FROM mytable
ORDER BY random()
LIMIT 2750
```

Although you'd probably want to stuff it in a local temp to summarize it since the groupings and selections would change at each execution.

Another idea if you want to keep consistent groupings might be to use [HASH()](https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.1.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Functions/Mathematical/HASH.htm) with a mod instead of purely random.  This will create the same GROUP value in each query.

```
SELECT ID, (HASH(ID) % 4)+1 as GROUP
FROM mytable
ORDER BY random()
LIMIT 2750
```